# Zoom Web SDK join audio doesn't work on mobile browsers

Tags: angular, sdk, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to use Zoom SDK for Angular for my PWA app, but when I'm opening the app on mobile browser or in mobile mode (debug mode on chrome or safari) it doesn't support join with audio
and doesn't support the responsive mode.

On a regular browser works fine!

Here is my code:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';

import {ZoomMtg} from '@zoomus/websdk';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-education-meeting',
  templateUrl: './education-meeting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./education-meeting.component.css']
})
export class EducationMeetingComponent implements OnInit {
  signatureEndpoint = 'http://7b4be2d6a655.ngrok.io'
  apiKey = 'MY KEY'
  meetingNumber = 12345211
  role = 0
  leaveUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/login'
  userName = 'MY USER'
  userEmail = 'mailblblbl@gmail.com'
  passWord = '455331'

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject(DOCUMENT) document, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.meetingNumber = +params['meetingId'];
      this.passWord = params['password'];
      // this.getSignature();
    });
  }

  getSignature() {
    this.httpClient.post(this.signatureEndpoint, {
      meetingNumber: this.meetingNumber,
      role: this.role
    }).toPromise().then((data: any) => {
      if (data.signature) {
        this.startMeeting(data.signature)
      } else {
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  startMeeting(signature) {
    document.getElementById('zmmtg-root').style.display = '-webkit-inline-box'

    ZoomMtg.init({
      leaveUrl: this.leaveUrl,
      disableInvite: true,
      showMeetingHeader: false,
      // disableCallOut: true,
      disableRecord: false,
      // disableJoinAudio: false,
      // isSupportAV: false,
      videoDrag: false,
      isSupportNonverbal: false,
      isSupportChat: false,
      isSupportQA: false,
      isSupportCC: false,
      sharingMode: 'fit',
      isLockBottom: false,
      audioPanelAlwaysOpen: true,
      meetingInfo: [],
      // disableVoIP: true, // optional
      disableReport: true, // optional
      screenShare: false,
      success: (success) => {
        ZoomMtg.join({
          signature: signature,
          meetingNumber: this.meetingNumber,
          userName: this.userName,
          apiKey: this.apiKey,
          userEmail: this.userEmail,
          passWord: this.passWord,
          success: (success) => {
            console.log(success)
          },
          error: (error) => {
            console.log(error)
          }
        })

      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    })
  }

}
```

Have someone found a workaround?

In addition, I would like to know if there is any way to remove the captcha check?

Answer (score 0):

At the time im writing this, Their current WebSdk version is 1.7.7. In this version connect to audio and few other functions not working on IOS. Please refer to this image which took from https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/sdk-reference/web-reference

[image]